# Seaborn Boxplot doesn't show Median Line (sometimes)?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, boxplot, median

I make my boxplots with seaborn 90% of the time no problem. But sometimes, it doesn't show the median line? Here the "ASD" Column doesn't have a median line, while the others do. What happened?? [image]

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12), dpi=300)

sns.boxplot(x="group2", y="WHO100Sozialscore", data=data_WHO, palette="Set2", 
            width=.5, ax=ax, showmeans=True ).set(xlabel='\nDiagnosis', ylabel='WHO-Social', title='Secondary Analysis WHO-Social Scores\n', yticks=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJR7l.png)

Comment: It seems sometimes the median line coincides with one of the quartile lines. You can use `data_WHO.describe()` to show the median and quartiles of the columns.

Comment: To better see the median when it is too close to one of the quartiles, you can change its color and linestyle.  E.g. `sns.boxplot(data=([[10, 20, 50, 80, 90], [10, 20, 20, 80, 90]]), color='skyblue', medianprops={'color': 'red', 'ls': ':', 'lw': 5})`